# DataBinder.Eval in c#

Tags: c#, eval, databinder

Hi anybody know how to use databinder.eval in c#

Actually I've tried this

```
LinkButton lnkName = new LinkButton();
lnkName.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval("object","<%#COURSE_ID%>");
```

it is showing error. Whats the wrong with this?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code please howing the complete usage.

Comment: Just I try to use DataBinder.Eval method through c# code instead of aspx inline. So it I tried like this. But I didnt get succeeded. DataBinder.Eval(object container,string expression) this is the signature. Here what does it mean by object container? Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Eval in the code behind of an aspx page.

this:

```
lnkName.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval("object","<%#COURSE_ID%>");
```

should be this:

```
lnkName.CommandArgument = YOUR_OBJECT_PROPERTY_HERE;
```

To fill in YOUR_OBJECT_PROPERTY_HERE you either need to specify the object.property etc like normal in C# code, or you'll have to use reflection to get the property value from the object (which is what eval does for you).

Here is a link showing how to use reflection to get the property information from an object.  You can use it to duplicate how eval works if you need to: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6099345.html

Link to DataBinder Eval Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

How the DataBinder Eval Method works (and why the author thinks it should be avoided) http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/09/20/425687.aspx

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. What does it mean by YOUR_OBJECT_PROPERTY_HERE ? I'm sorry can you give me an example?

Comment: @jestges it would be something like: 
[ObjectInstance].[Property] or CollegeClass.CourseID

Comment: I've gone throug many examples. In every example they are showing with static controls like <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnname" OnCommand="lnkbtnname_Click" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NAME") %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton> But I want to create this link buttondynamically and want to set the databinder.eval

Answer (score 4):

For Example in design page you can use like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CommandName="Edit" 
    CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
    CssClass="cursor_hand" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
```

Code Behind:

```
int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex > -1)
    {

        string h = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnName").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: For a repeater it's DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ColumnName")

Answer (score 0):

You should use Eval expression and `<% %>` in *.aspx code not with C# code.

Comment: Then what is the use of DataBinder.Eval method in c#?