# How to access a valuer of GridView row based on checkBox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Hi I have a GridView with a multiple rows and columns. I've also added a checkBox in a grid view..

But now I'm having troubles of accessing the values of a particular row(s) whose checkBox(es) are checked.

Because upon pressing a button I want to change values of one column from unregistered to registered.

And Another button Should forward an account id of a checked row to another page where all the details of the entry will be outputed.

Does anyone know how to do that?

here are code segments I'm using:

Tis is the code of the GridView and the Button:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="1500px">
        <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckBox" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

              </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>


     <asp:Button ID="DetailsBtn" runat="server" Text="See Details" />
     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
     <asp:Button ID="RegBtn" runat="server" Text="Mark Registered" />
```

Here is the code of populating the GridView

```
Try
        myconn.Open()
        Dim sqlstring As String = "SELECT a.account_id AS 'No', a.accountid_number .BLA BLA BLA"
        Dim smd As MySqlCommand
        smd = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, myconn)
        smd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(smd)
        Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()

        myconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        Dim exmess As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "')"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", exmess, True)
        myconn.Close()
    End Try
```

And What should i do for the button here?

```
Protected Sub RegBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles RegBtn.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through the gridview rows, find **myCheckBox** in each row and see whether it's checked or not, here's an example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995776/how-can-i-delete-the-selected-rows-checkbox-used-from-the-gridview-on-click-of/14995982#14995982

Answer (score 2):

To find checked rows in gridview:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
 Checkbox cbox = (Checkbox)row.FindControl("myCheckBox");
 if(cbox.Checked)
 {
   // do your stuff ...
 }
 else
 { // do your other stuff ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank. But how can I put value in database. I have to extract Id number from the row somehow to put it to the query. Don't i?

Comment: Yes. But i have to extract a id number from the row somehow to put it in the query. That's the problem

Comment: You can simply add hiddenfield to gridview and you can get the value of hiddenfield like checkbox. Put that hiddenfield after checkbox. <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenID" runat="server" value="<%#Eval("account_id") %>" /> Then in codebehind you can get the id like that. HiddenField id = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hiddenId");

Comment: do we assign it to the vb/C3 variable in code behind by this code: `HiddenField id = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hiddenId");`

Comment: Actually yes but i don't prefer this. First add that HiddenField under Checkbox. Then call it in codebehind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637330/databinder-eval-in-c-sharp

Comment: actually in my case the ID  column comes right after check box. What would be the backend code for this scenario?

Comment: I tryed this `Dim selectedRow As String = GridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Item("account_id").Value` but the program complains that Current Row isn't a member of GridView

Comment: I managed to cum up with this code. But return value doesn't return anything.I don't know where is my mistake `For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
             If (CType(gvr.findcontrol("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)).Checked = True Then
                Primaryid = gvr.Cells("account_id").Text
            End If
        Next gvr`